# Using Azure Yaml pipeline to call powershell RestMethod with secret variable in body

Tags: azure, powershell, auth0, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to automate a step in our Azure yaml pipeline to delete some users from Auth0 using PowerShell and RestMethod, but for some reason the secret is either not used correctly or changed or something.

I have set the secret as a variable and then tried using it either directly in the script or through setting it on the task as well as an environment variable, but no luck.

Here is my last iteration, but still no joy, could anyone shed some light on the issue?

```
$api = "api/v2/"
$audience = $audience + $api
$secret = "$env:AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"
$test = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret))

Write-Host $clientSecret.substring(0,10)
Write-Host $test.substring(0,10)
Write-Host $audience
Write-Host $clientId

$Body = @{
    client_id = $clientId
    client_secret = $test OR $secret OR $clientSecret
    audience = $audience
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
}

Write-Host 'Getting token'
$response = Invoke-RestMethod https://mytenant.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token `
-Method 'POST' `
-ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8' `
-Body ($Body | ConvertTo-Json)
```

As shown, I have tried using test, secret and clientSecret as the secret, but also no luck. The write host at the start does show the correct starting characters for $clientSecret

Am I missing something basic or is this just not possible using RestMethod?

Comment: To me looks like rather an OAuth2.0 issue. Are you sure it's not `https://mytenant.eu.auth0.com/oauth2/token` there? Or maybe you need to set the `scope`?

Comment: When I run this code locally and pass the secret as a param it works perfectly, just in the yaml pipeline it does not process the secret correctly

Answer (score 1):

Ended up going scorched earth and completely deleted the pipelines and started again, this is the powershell script I ended up with that worked.

```
$token = "/oauth/token"
$https = "https://"
$api = "/api/v2/"

$audience = $https + $domain + $api
$tokenUrl = $https + $domain + $token

Write-Host 'Getting token'
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $tokenUrl `
    -Method 'POST' `
    -ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8' `
    -Body (@{ 
        client_id     = $clientId 
        client_secret = "$env:AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET" 
        audience      = $audience
        grant_type    = "client_credentials" 
    } | ConvertTo-Json)
```